# Node.js client connection and Azure Transaction billing cost

Tags: node.js, azure

I am quite new to Node.js usage inside Azure platform.   What I understand is , Node.js technology  is like broadcast event model from "Server---->to-->Client" data push.  Technically, node.js client is connected to node.js(Server) via long polling permanent connection.  It means, node.js(Server) keep sending some heart beats to client to maintain the connection alive.

In such cases, if we deploy node.js server in Azure webrole/workerrole,  if 100 browsers are connected to node.js server HTTP url,   there will be always http heartbeats flowing from Azure server to client browsers.  If my assumption is correct, does azure take this heartbeats as transactions into total billing.   Can anyone help to get some inputs on how node.js impact the billing for 1000s of browsers/http clients connected to a node.js running inside azure.

I tried running fiddler web traffic tool in node.js/Client PC and observed that, every one minute one HTTP is invoked.  Does this mean,  HTTP handshake happening every minitue between client PC and node.js/server machine while node.js server is idle.   If yes,  how node.js help reduce the traffic between client and server ( like Periodic Polling  Vs   Long Polling).

Two different questions :

1)  billing cost of using node.js inside azure ?

2)  why I see http reply signal in node.js client PC while server is idle ?

Thanks
Veda

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the second part of your question, but as far as billing goes, transactions only apply to Azure storage, CDN and access control.  In your case all you are charged for is for the data volume of the responses from your servers (data that comes into the data centre you're not charged for).  The most this will cost you is $0.19 per GB if you're hosting out of Asia Pacific.  It's only $0.12 per GB if you're hosting out of the US.  You will be spending much, much more money on compute instances.

Comment: Hello Knightpfhor, Thanks for some insight.  Actually my confusion is ,  in node.js  Server--->to--->Client HTTP connection, is like permanent connection (long polling). For example, i have total number of node.js client is 100 machines,  it means 100 HTTP permanent connections talking to Azure Node.js 24 hours.    I am clear, the data going out from node.js server to client is billable.  However, is there any charge on "HTTP connection" side, since azure cloud is always responding/pining to all 100 clients 24 hours.   Did you get the kind of doubt I have.   Sorry to be naive, please clarify.

Comment: Nope, like I said you are only charged for the outgoing data.  There is no charge for connecting to the server.

Comment: Hello Knightpfhor,  I am curious to double check. When I did debugging of socket.io Client-----> socket.io Server  to exchange messages like chat application,  I see lot of heartbeat messages exchanged both sides.   Meaning, client sends heart beat,  server also sends back heart beats.    Will this heart beats taken into account for billing , while using node.js/socket.io ?   If azure charges lot of money for this heart beats messages ( since data going into/out of server), the billing will be high right ? Please assist with info.

Comment: From memory you get charged $0.15 per GB of data that transferred out of your role.  If the heartbeat was really big, say 1KB, you would have to send 1,000,000 of these heartbeat messages before it would cost you 15 cents.  I don't think you need to worry about it too much.